# How to pass parameters from component and access them in js controller Lightning App

Tags: lightning-aura-components

How can i pass parameters from lightning app component and access them in java-script controller where I can set or pass them to my event. Or is there a way out how i can know which attribute in my component was clicked inside my js controller. 
Actually I am iterating an array in my component and displaying all the iterations in tabular form setting dynamic ids to them, now when a user clicks an idem i want to pass its id and few more attributes to the controller, Can anyone help me with this.

**Component**

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.all}" var="xxx">
    <aura:if isTrue="{!xxx != v.search}">
        <span class="sub_main_owner_icon">
        <img aura:id="{!xxx}" onclick="{!c.loadDetails}" src="/Owner.png" />
        </span>
    </aura:if>
</aura:iteration>
```

**Controller**

```
loadDetails : function(component, event, helper) {
    loadDetails.setParams({
        **I want to pass values here from my component**
        "xxx": component.get("v.xxx.Id")
        "account": component.get("v.xxx.Id")
   });
```

Comment: Some example code would be helpful.

Comment: Try event.getSource(), see if that gets you the component you expect.

Comment: I think if it is just the ID the `getSource` option might work. If you need more params, you may need to create your own special wrapper component with attributes that are set and then passed. The event handler would then be on the wrapper component, instead of this one. Sorry I don't have time to build out an example and show, but hopefully this comment sends you in the right direction.

Comment: Right the child component could throw an event that the parent handles. Our support for event delegation is weak at the moment.

Comment: @Kris Gray Could you tell me how can i pass parameters on simple click on some DOM attribute, If i want to access the values say I have 10 images on my DOM dynamically created with different aura IDs, how could i know in my Js Controller, which image was clicked. and i would like to know is there a way i can pass n no. of parameters from my comp. to js controller onClick(). as in traditional programming we would pass as js function parameters or via HTTP POST or GET methods.

Comment: You certainly can't pass any parameters to a controller method, that's against the principles of the controller. You should be able to set them on the component, then act upon them in the controller based on what component fired the event.

Answer (score 3):

What I do is add a data-* style attribute to the element that is triggering the event.

```
<img aura:id="{!xxx}" onclick="{!c.loadDetails}" src="/Owner.png" data-id="{!xxx}" />
```

and then in the handler, pull that id out with

```
loadDetails: function(component, event, helper){
   var el = event.srcElement;
   var id = el.dataset.id;//id here is from 'data-id' in the element
```

now I don't know (off the top of my head) how cross browser that code is, but it appears to work in Salesforce1.

Answer (score 0):

In the component, create a div with the unique id/class/aura:id. Then in the controller, you can use jquery to grab the value/attribute (or component.get). I usually pass component, event, helper in the function, and inside that controller's function, you can access most values and attributes if the component is passed in as parameter